# Spring GeneratedValue annotation usage

Tags: spring, jpa, entity

Let's say that I have a `Car` entity:

```
@Entity 
public class Car {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
      private Integer id;
```

How does spring know what value to autoincrement when I add a new object to the database?

Comment: Spring does not know anything at all about `GeneratedValue`. A JPA Provider does. Spring does not implement the JPA API.

Comment: Spring Couchbase...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Here is a [good explanation of primary keys generation strategies](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-generate-primary-keys/)**

> ### There are 4 options to generate primary keys
>
> #### GenerationType.AUTO
>
> The GenerationType.AUTO is the **default generation type** and lets the
>   persistence provider choose the generation strategy.
>
> If you use Hibernate as your persistence provider, it selects a
>   generation strategy based on the database specific dialect. For most
>   popular databases, **it selects GenerationType.SEQUENCE**.
>
> #### GenerationType.IDENTITY
>
> The GenerationType.IDENTITY is the **easiest** to use but **not the best one
>   from a performance point of view**. It relies on an auto-incremented
>   database column and lets the database generate a new value with each
>   insert operation. From a database point of view, this is very efficient because the auto-increment columns are highly optimized, and it doesn’t require any additional statements.
>
> This approach has a significant drawback if you use Hibernate.
>   Hibernate requires a primary key value for each managed entity and
>   therefore has to perform the insert statement immediately. This
>   prevents it from using different optimization techniques like JDBC
>   batching.
>
> #### GenerationType.SEQUENCE
>
> The GenerationType.SEQUENCE uses a database sequence to generate
>   unique values. It requires additional select statements to get the
>   next value from a database sequence. But this has **no performance
>   impact for most applications**.
>
> If you don’t provide any additional information, Hibernate will
>   request the next value from its default sequence. You can change that
>   by referencing the name of a `@SequenceGenerator` in the generator
>   attribute of the `@GeneratedValue` annotation. The `@SequenceGenerator`
>   annotation lets you define the name of the generator, the name, and
>   schema of the database sequence and the allocation size of the
>   sequence.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@SequenceGenerator(name="car_generator", sequenceName = "car_seq", allocationSize=50)
private Long id;
```

(Side note: Usually prefer `Long` for ids instead of `Integer` so you're less likely to run out)

> #### GenerationType.TABLE
>
> The GenerationType.TABLE gets **only rarely used nowadays**. It simulates
>   a sequence by storing and updating its current value in a database
>   table which requires the use of pessimistic locks which put all
>   transactions into a sequential order. This slows down your
>   application, and you should, therefore, **prefer the
>   GenerationType.SEQUENCE**, if your database supports sequences, which
>   most popular databases do.