# When is data persisted to the database when using GenerationType.IDENTITY vs GenerationType.SEQUENCE?

Tags: jpa

Context: Java EE application should minimize the risk of data loss as much as possible. This can come at the cost of performance for now, as the load on the server is not that high.

My understanding is that `GenerationType.IDENTITY` performs an immediate insert operation into the database when the Object is instantiated, whereas `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` performs a read operation on the database to retrieve the next value of a database sequence. The source used for this information is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676403/spring-generatedvalue-annotation-usage). Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Given my understanding, should `GenerationType.IDENTITY` be preferred over `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` in this context since data is persisted to the database earlier?

Comment: The short answer is that this depends on the database. For example, Mysql doesn't support sequences, Oracle doesn't support AUTOINCREMENT columns so sequences are the only choice, I think Postgress supports both and when autoincrement is used a sequence is used under the hood .

Comment: It depends on the JPA provider also. Also IDENTITY will mean that you cannot take advantage of batch inserts

Comment: Thanks! Hibernate is the JPA provider. I will go with AUTO instead, and let Hibernate make a judgement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate persists data immediately for entities marked with GenerationType.IDENTITY as Hibernate needs to know the primary key value to maintain the session. But this has flaw, as this generation type wont be able to use many Hibernate optimization techniques.

For entities marked with GenerationType.SEQUENCE, Hibernate internally fires a select query when an object is persisted using session.save() or session.persist() and populates the primary key. Then it can save the data when the session is Flushed/Committed.
Moreover, since the entity is being populated with the primary key , Hibernate can internally use optimization techniques on these entities like JDBC Batching and all.

More information can be seen here - https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-generate-primary-keys/

Comment: Thanks! Had a look at the [Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators) too, which had additional caveats regarding GenerationType.IDENTITY. Will leave it on AUTO instead in this case, and let Hibernate make a judgement.