# javax validation does not validate notNull

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-couchbase

I have a springBoot 2.1.9.RELEASE application that uses Spring Data for Couchbase

I have this object

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Hostel<T> {

    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty("_location")
    private T location;

}
```

and this other one

```
@Document
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = { "id" })
@Builder
public class HTMDoc {

    @Id
    private String id;
    @NotNull
    @Field
    private Hostel hostel;

}
```

on the service

```
public HTMDoc create(@Valid HTMDoc doc) {
    return repository.save(doc);
}
```

on the test

```
service.create(new HTMDoc());
```

but when I save I got this error instead of the validation NotNull in the hostel field

```
 org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: An ID property is needed, but not found/could not be generated on this entity.
```

Comment: The id field does not have _@NotNull, why it should validate it? I would put it there and I would consider to apply the _@GeneratedValue too (if the id is not provided in the create call...) (hm how to write java annotations here so to avoid stackoverflow engine recoginizing it as user mention?)

Comment: but the hostel field does

Comment: Yes, and that means that it will be checked whether the HTMDoc.hostel is null or not. But you have told nothing to the validation engine about the other field.

Comment: Which @NotNull annotation are you using? Show the full package.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the `@org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated` annotation over your service class to enable validation.

```
@Validated
@Service
public class DocService {
  public HTMDoc create(@Valid HTMDoc doc) {
    return repository.save(doc);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following annotation to the id and give it a try:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationStrategy.UNIQUE)
private String id;
```

More info about `@GeneratedValue` annotation can be found in this great answer: [Spring GeneratedValue annotation usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676403/spring-generatedvalue-annotation-usage)

Answer (score 0):

Put the annotation on the getter.

Maybe the validation is not supported in private fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Hostel<T> {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty("_location")
    private T location;

}
```

Using @Id on any property is mandatory in Model classes.

Answer (score 0):

please add the following syntax on your id field

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Hostel<T> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty("_location")
    private T location;

}
```

also use the validate annotation in your service class.

```
@Validated
@Service
public class DocService {
  public HTMDoc create(@Valid HTMDoc doc) {
    return repository.save(doc);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the @Validated annotation in your classes to inform the spring boot that these classes are should be validated by javax validations.

```
@Validated
@Component
public class Phone {
 //Your logic
}
```